# Prevent MacBook from Booting

Tags: macbook

I am looking for a easy way to make the MacBook un-bootable? I am trying to get my kids to focus on homework instead of going to Facebook, etc. We have a second computer in the kitchen which they can use for homework so that we can watch what they are doing. Also, I want it to go back to normal after finals in December.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to solve a human problem with a technology solution.  You can make it unbootable by locking it in a cabinet.  When you want it bootable again, take it out of the cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just put a password on it? That is an easier way to solve this problem then trying to make it not boot.